# How do i split an array per column for all columns? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

Hello JavaScript peers,

I have an array that was created from data from a csv file that looks like the following:

[image: array from CSV file]

each array index for example array[0] are the headers in which there are 87 in this case.  Every other array within that array are the rows.

I need to grab that data and split it between columns

the following code does just that but just for the first column:

```
      var specialCounter = 0;
        for(var j = 1; j<vm.lines.length; j++){
            vm.columns.push(vm.lines[j][0]);

            if(specialCounter >= vm.lines[j][0].length)
                specialCounter = 0;
            else
                specialCounter++;
        }

        vm.columnData.columnData= vm.columns;

        console.log(vm.columnData);
```

This is the array that it spits out.

[image: array]

How do I, do this for all of the columns in this array?

maybe with a structure like `vm.dataPerColumn = [{column1: [...], column2: [...], etc...]`

Comment: Aren't you over complicating it if you do like that? You already know which column you want so writing `column[0][15]` would refer to `columnData[0]["column16"]`

Comment: @Pavlo I need to have it in a for loop because once I get all the data per column I need to  find each distinct value and how many times it occurs in that column

Comment: are you sure that array[0] isn't all the headers? That's what i looks like from your picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array, [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) sub-array check if the key exists, and if not create the key on the result object (`r`). Push the current item to the key:

```js
var arr = [['h1', 1, 2, 3], ['h2', 4 , 5 , 6], ['h3', 7, 8, 9]];

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, a) {
  a.forEach(function(s, i) {
    var key = i === 0 ? 'headers' : 'column' + i;
    
    r[key] || (r[key] = []); // if key not found on result object, add the key with empty array as the value
    
    r[key].push(s);
  });
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: when i ran your code, i see data missing from the array? there is 472 rows and when i run the array through your snippet, result comes only with 465 items in the array and not the full 472? why is that?

Comment: Create a codepen (or similar), and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the description and looking at the picture, it seems like the headers are in `array[0]`

```
const vm = {};
vm.lines = [["$", "house", "car"],[5, 10, 15],[25,35,45]]; 

const headers = vm.lines[0];
const data = vm.lines.slice(1);

const columns = data.reduce((newColumns, row) => {
    for(let i=0;i<row.length;i++){
        if(newColumns.length-1 < i){ //first column;
            newColumns.push([]);
        }
        newColumns[i].push(row[i]);
    }
    return newColumns;
}, []);

const columnsWithHeaders = headers.map((header, index) => ({[header]:columns[index]}));

console.log(columnsWithHeaders);
```

You requested column1, column2 etc, but it doesn't really make sense when you already have an array, so i put the header name together with the respective column, then you can reference it directly

What i have done is to separate the headers and the data. So you don't have to worry about the first line,

Then i have converted the rows into columns, and after that you can just go through the headers and add the column array to each header.

Comment: when i ran your code, i see data missing from the array? there is 472 rows and when i run the array through your snippet, result comes only with 465 items in the array and not the full 472? why is that?

Comment: Maybe the `slice` method, hard to say when i don't have the data